# Override and function and still get a modified information

Tags: debugging, lua, overriding

Is there any way to override a function and still get the result of:

```
debug.getinfo(pairs).linedefined == -1 ?
```

I want to override an function but still bypass the check of `debug.getinfo`
otherwise or can I override `debug.getinfo` ?

Comment: why would you want to do this? how do you debug your code if you mess up your debug info?

Comment: You can overwrite debug.getinfo like any other function. It is not very clear what you want to achieve. Please provide more details and an example.

Comment: It seems as if you're making a sandbox in Lua. You can just override getinfo (and traceback and everything else you want) to make the sandbox less detectable.

Comment: If you are creating a sandbox in Lua, then you *must* remove the `debug` library. The point of a sandbox is to create a zone of safety, but the `debug` library's purpose is (in part) to allow doing unsafe things. They contradict each other. You may be able to wrap certain `debug` library functions, but it's better to just chuck the whole thing.

Comment: i want to disable this function debug.getinfo.linedefined from working but if called for (pairs) it will give you a specific result that i declared so more like a variable not a function i don't if this is understandable :/

Comment: A function is a value with one or more references to it. If you want a different function referred to by `debug.getinfo`, just set it to that different function value. If you want to use the original function in your new function (or elsewhere), simply grab the value before you change it. Does that apply to your need?

Comment: @TomBlodget that wanna it hit yes but it would be cool like if you write to me few lines of code to just let me begin in this

Comment: I'm with @warspyking so this is more educational than "helpful"… `debug.getinfo = function(f) return (f==pairs and {linedefined = -1 }) or nil end`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can store references to the old functions in a lookup table, and then wrap getinfo to check this table before calling itself regularly. This would effectively accomplish what you're attempting to do.

However I must stress that if you are sandboxing, or somehow prohibiting or restricting a user in any way, disabling the debug library is **necessary**. Yes, you can sandbox them, but IMO it would be just as difficult as sandboxing bytecode with loadstring (speaking if which you should also disable that).

I won't give you a code example however, since it's highly discouraged to do this, I hope you find another option.

Comment: Yeah that's the idea but i would of love a an example to just let me begin this thing
if not how is it possible to disable library ? (still not advane in lua )

Comment: @user ```debug = nil```